# How to refactor a repetitive line of code java

Tags: java, refactoring, jbutton

I need to create a lot of buttons with information from an excel file, each button have different information but right now the method that creates the buttons is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit so I was thinking of refactoring the method that creates the buttons but I don't know if its possible considering each button is a little different than the previous one, here is an example of what im doing:

```
JRadioButton rdbtn1IOE1 = new JRadioButton("Cruzamiento con algún Cuerpo de Agua - Sí");
    rdbtn1IOE1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            IOE.set(0,0.8);
            label_IOE.setText("IOE:"+(IOE.get(0)+IOE.get(1)+IOE.get(2)+IOE.get(3)+IOE.get(4)+IOE.get(5)+IOE.get(6)+IOE.get(7)+
                    IOE.get(8)+IOE.get(9)+IOE.get(10)+IOE.get(11)+IOE.get(12)+IOE.get(13)+IOE.get(14)+IOE.get(15)+IOE.get(16)+IOE.get(17)+
                    IOE.get(18)+IOE.get(19)+IOE.get(20)+IOE.get(21))+"% ");

        }
    });
    JRadioButton rdbtn2IOE1 = new JRadioButton("Cruzamiento con algún Cuerpo de Agua - No");
    rdbtn2IOE1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            IOE.set(0,0.0);
            label_IOE.setText("IOE:"+(IOE.get(0)+IOE.get(1)+IOE.get(2)+IOE.get(3)+IOE.get(4)+IOE.get(5)+IOE.get(6)+IOE.get(7)+
                    IOE.get(8)+IOE.get(9)+IOE.get(10)+IOE.get(11)+IOE.get(12)+IOE.get(13)+IOE.get(14)+IOE.get(15)+IOE.get(16)+IOE.get(17)+
                    IOE.get(18)+IOE.get(19)+IOE.get(20)+IOE.get(21))+"% ");

        }
    });
    JRadioButton rdbtnNoDataIOE1 = new JRadioButton("No Data");
    rdbtnNoDataIOE1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            IOE.set(0,0.0);
            label_IOE.setText("IOE:"+(IOE.get(0)+IOE.get(1)+IOE.get(2)+IOE.get(3)+IOE.get(4)+IOE.get(5)+IOE.get(6)+IOE.get(7)+
                    IOE.get(8)+IOE.get(9)+IOE.get(10)+IOE.get(11)+IOE.get(12)+IOE.get(13)+IOE.get(14)+IOE.get(15)+IOE.get(16)+IOE.get(17)+
                    IOE.get(18)+IOE.get(19)+IOE.get(20)+IOE.get(21))+"% ");

        }
    });

    JRadioButton rdbtn1IOE2 = new JRadioButton("< 100 metros");
    rdbtn1IOE2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            IOE.set(1,0.1);
            label_IOE.setText("IOE:"+(IOE.get(0)+IOE.get(1)+IOE.get(2)+IOE.get(3)+IOE.get(4)+IOE.get(5)+IOE.get(6)+IOE.get(7)+
                    IOE.get(8)+IOE.get(9)+IOE.get(10)+IOE.get(11)+IOE.get(12)+IOE.get(13)+IOE.get(14)+IOE.get(15)+IOE.get(16)+IOE.get(17)+
                    IOE.get(18)+IOE.get(19)+IOE.get(20)+IOE.get(21))+"% ");

        }
    });
    JRadioButton rdbtnNoDataIOE2 = new JRadioButton("No Data");
    rdbtnNoDataIOE2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            IOE.set(1,0.0);
            label_IOE.setText("IOE:"+(IOE.get(0)+IOE.get(1)+IOE.get(2)+IOE.get(3)+IOE.get(4)+IOE.get(5)+IOE.get(6)+IOE.get(7)+
                    IOE.get(8)+IOE.get(9)+IOE.get(10)+IOE.get(11)+IOE.get(12)+IOE.get(13)+IOE.get(14)+IOE.get(15)+IOE.get(16)+IOE.get(17)+
                    IOE.get(18)+IOE.get(19)+IOE.get(20)+IOE.get(21))+"% ");

        }
    });
    JRadioButton rdbtn2IOE2 = new JRadioButton(">= 100 to <= 200 metros");
    rdbtn2IOE2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            IOE.set(1,0.05);
            label_IOE.setText("IOE:"+(IOE.get(0)+IOE.get(1)+IOE.get(2)+IOE.get(3)+IOE.get(4)+IOE.get(5)+IOE.get(6)+IOE.get(7)+
                    IOE.get(8)+IOE.get(9)+IOE.get(10)+IOE.get(11)+IOE.get(12)+IOE.get(13)+IOE.get(14)+IOE.get(15)+IOE.get(16)+IOE.get(17)+
                    IOE.get(18)+IOE.get(19)+IOE.get(20)+IOE.get(21))+"% ");

        }
    });
```

I hope I explained this well, thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the "little difference"? Maybe you can write a custom `ActionListener`/`JRadioButton` class which accepts a few parameters?

Comment: your string inside ' label_IOE.setText("X");' will be same follow above format only?

Comment: @Marvin each button has a different name and they're divided into button groups so lets say there are 5 buttons in a group, this group has assigned a place in an array list and the value of that place in the array list is set depending on which button is selected

Comment: @karthik yeah the setText method for the label is the same for every button

Comment: what exactly do you want to refactor? only `label_IOE.setText` or full button creation?

Comment: @karthik I want to refactor the full button creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactoring the code you have, either extend `JRadioButton` passing the "differences" to the constructor:

```
public class MyJRadioButton extends JRadioButton {
    public MyJRadioButton(String title, final int x, final double y) {
        super(title);
        addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                IOE.set(x, y);
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder("IOE:");
                for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
                    text.append(IOE.get(i));
                label_IOE.setText(text + "% ");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then to use, for example:

```
JRadioButton rdbtnNoDataIOE1 = new MyJRadioButton("No Data", 0, 0.0);
```

Or if you prefer not to extend the component, here's a factory method version:

```
public static JRadioButton create(String title, final int x, final double y) {
    JRadioButton button = JRadioButton(title);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            IOE.set(x, y);
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder("IOE:");
            for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
                text.append(IOE.get(i));
            label_IOE.setText(text + "% ");
        }
    });
    return button;
}
```

which you use like:

```
JRadioButton rdbtnNoDataIOE1 = create("No Data", 0, 0.0);
```

Comment: There is rarely a good reason to extend concrete subclasses of JComponents and it leasts to really poor design over time.

Comment: @Daniel that's a matter of opinion, but because I'm feeling generous I've provided a factory method option.

Comment: @Bohemian after changing some parts of your factory method I could finally make it work thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

This looks to me like you could create a single ActionListener subclass, with a constructor that takes the two parameters that you are passing to IOE.set.

```
public class IOESetActionListener extends ActionListener {
    private final int a;
    private final double b;
    public IOESetActionListener(int a, double b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        IOE.set(a, b);
        final StringBuilder builder = new StirngBuilder("IOE:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 22; ++i) {  
          builder.append(IOE.get(i));
        }
        label_IOE.setText(builder.append("% ").toString());
    }
}
```

Then your buttons can just be (for example) `rdbtn1IOE1.addActionListener(new IOESetActionListener(0,0.8));`

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel, with this constructor will I be able to set the names of the buttons as well? Because I need to set the names of each button manually.

Comment: If that's the case, you'll want to extend AbstractAction instead, and pas that to the constructor of the JButton, not to the addActionListener.